# I have two columns, I want the second column to have the same values as the first column

Tags: postgresql, text, duplicates, integer

I have two columns, I want the second column to have the same values as the first column always, in PostgreSQL.

The columns are `landmark_id` (integer) and `name` (varchar), I want the `name` column to always have the same values (id's) from `landmark_id`.

```
landmark_id (integer) | name (varchar)
1                       1
2                       2
3                       3
```

Comment: Don't store the same values twice. Create a view instad.

Comment: landmark_id column will always have an integer value (0, 1, 2...), I just want the same values to be updated into the 'name' column too, which is varchar. (0, 1, 2.. aswell)

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you would want to do that, but I can think of two ways to accomplish your request. One is by using a generated column

```
CREATE TABLE g (
  landmark_id int,
  name varchar(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (landmark_id::varchar) STORED
)
```

and the other is by enforcing a constraint

```
CREATE TABLE c (
  landmark_id int,
  name varchar(100),
  CONSTRAINT equality_cc CHECK (landmark_id = name::varchar)
)
```

Both approaches will cause the `name` column to occupy disk space. The first approach will not allow you to specify the `name` column in `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements. In the latter case, you will be forced to specify both columns when inserting.
You could also have used a trigger to update the second column.

Late edit: Others suggested using a view. I agree that it's a better idea than what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `view`, as suggested by @jarlh in comments. This automatically generates column `name` for you on the fly. This is usually preferred to storing essentially the same data multiple times as in an actual table, where the data occupies more disk space and also can get out of sync. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW landmarks_names AS
SELECT landmark_id,
       landmark_id::text AS name
FROM landmarks;
```